# Greasemonkey: how to get HTTP response headers request URL on a page with a redirection?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

Is there a way to retrieve HTTP header location of page loaded from Greasemonkey (so using javascript)? In debugger, it's named in "Headers > Request url".

I can't to do a new request using XMLHttpRequest() on page, because the page is redirected (307 Temporary Redirect or 308 Permanent Redirect).

I found nothing helping me on the web.

Comment: Should I use browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests